# SAPUI5 change table binding from ODataModel to JSONModel

Tags: sapui5

I created a table and used an `ODataModel` for the data binding. Everything is working fine. The template defines the properties which should be bound to the columns.

However, at some point I need to bind a `JSONModel` to the table instead of the `ODataModel` (because the data should be adapted but it should not actually be updated in the backend). The data should be just the same at the beginning.

So far I created the service request to get all the data. Then I added it to the `JSONModel` (using the `setData` function).

Now I wonder how to replace the two models. Is it even possible to change the binding (and table properties) so that the `JSONModel` is bound or do I need to create a new table?

I am thankful for every hint!

Comment: Why would you not load the data into the JSONModel for the table straight away then?

Comment: I am currently using the ODataModel because I can load the data step-by-step (using the growingThreshold property). The JSONModel is only necessary in some optional case which is not often used. Therefore, I only want to use the JSONModel (without $top request parameter) if it is really necessary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the new JSON model to the existing control using **setModel** member function:

```
oTable.setModel(yourNewJSONModel);
```

if you have named model (so, your binding looks like "{modelName>/property}" then you should assign new model this way:

```
oTable.setModel(yourNewJSONModel, "modelName");
```

Probably you have to rebind rows (or items) aggregation depending on the table kind you use (sap.ui.table.Table or sap.m.Table):

```
oTable.bindRows({
   path: "/somePropertyPath",
   model: "modelName"
});
```

If all the field names for rows are the same then it should work.

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me with `oTable.bindItems("modelName>/results", oTemplate);` (oTemplate = template of the table).